# Camera App in Portrait Mode

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera-intent

We are making an application which supports both tablet devices and mobile devices. We have provided different layouts for both the mobiles and tablets. We support landscape orientation for tablets and portrait for mobile.

Now we have one screen in app which allows user to open camera and take picture which then will be saved and shown to the user once the user will close camera.

App works fine for tablet devices. But for mobile devices, it crashes once the camera app is closed after taking the picture. I then found out that Camera app for devices other than Nexus(Vanilla Android in general) have landscape orientation by default (App works fine for nexus devices) and so it recreates-reinitializes my main activity (from which I have loaded my fragment) after closing that camera app.

After trying to dig out some more, I found that camera app has orientation landscape in it's source code file so I can't change that. That leaves me with 2 options :

1) I need to integrate camera in my app only -- it can be done but I don't want to do this option as it doesn't seem appropriate.

2) I need to implement some way to save instance of activity -- I have only one activity (to support tablet layout) which loads all different fragments (around 30-35 fragments I guess - may be more than that) and all this fragments have it's own callbacks to activity. The fragment which opens the camera app is also opened by some callback method in activity so it seems very complex to implement this also. There will a huge number of variables to be retained which is not good.

Please give me some other suggestion as to what other things can be done ? Otherwise I will have to integrate camera in my app itself.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what exactly is the problem when the re initialization of Main Activity takes place ? Why does the application crash ?

Comment: you can simply use third party camera lib in your app because your question is not only limited to nexus n tabs...there are lots of devices..so this lib work for all you should use this one - https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Comment: @ShivamVerma : What happens is when the camera is closed, and the orientation is changed now, the main activity is loaded again and it will throw null pointer exception in the variables because as I don't have state retained, those variables are coming null.

Comment: @RohitGoswami : I am planning to try something like that but I want to find out some middle solution. If I won't find anything, then I am gonna do that only which you suggested.

Comment: have you tried adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|" tag to your activity ? This'll prevent the activity from getting recreated when the orientation changes.

Comment: @ShivamVerma : Yes. I tried that but still getting the same error.